# Error messages while verifying code with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visualstudio

I move recently to use Visual Studio Code to develop for arduino. But I'm receiving some error messages while I'm trying to verify my code that confuse me. The messages are:

```
2020-04-12T13:53:40.409Z INFO c.a.u.n.HttpConnectionManager:148 [cc.arduino.packages.discoverers.serial.SerialDiscovery] Connect to https://builder.arduino.cc/builder/v1/boards/0x8087/0x0ACA, method=GET, request id=20892E5EE7E84976
2020-04-12T13:53:40.926Z INFO c.a.u.n.HttpConnectionManager:152 [cc.arduino.packages.discoverers.serial.SerialDiscovery] Request complete URL="https://builder.arduino.cc/builder/v1/boards/0x8087/0x0ACA", method=GET, response code=404, request id=20892E5EE7E84976, headers={null=[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Server=[nginx], Connection=[keep-alive], Vary=[Origin], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], Content-Length=[0], Date=[Sun, 12 Apr 2020 13:53:41 GMT]}
2020-04-12T13:53:40.926Z WARN p.a.h.BoardCloudResolver:64 [cc.arduino.packages.discoverers.serial.SerialDiscovery] Fail to get the Vid Pid information from the builder response code=404
2020-04-12T13:53:40.937Z INFO c.a.u.n.HttpConnectionManager:148 [cc.arduino.packages.discoverers.serial.SerialDiscovery] Connect to https://builder.arduino.cc/builder/v1/boards/0x8087/0x0ACA, method=GET, request id=D8C082A90BB14CDF
2020-04-12T13:53:41.044Z INFO c.a.u.n.HttpConnectionManager:152 [cc.arduino.packages.discoverers.serial.SerialDiscovery] Request complete URL="https://builder.arduino.cc/builder/v1/boards/0x8087/0x0ACA", method=GET, response code=404, request id=D8C082A90BB14CDF, headers={null=[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Server=[nginx], Connection=[keep-alive], Vary=[Origin], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], Content-Length=[0], Date=[Sun, 12 Apr 2020 13:53:41 GMT]}
2020-04-12T13:53:41.044Z WARN p.a.h.BoardCloudResolver:64 [cc.arduino.packages.discoverers.serial.SerialDiscovery] Fail to get the Vid Pid information from the builder response code=404
```

Based on this output it seems something is happening with these URLs but when I try to do the same in the same computer with Arduino IDE there is no such error messages.

Does anybody know how to get rid of these messages?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Downgrade your Arduino IDE to a version below 1.8.10.

Answer (score 1):

It works with Arduino IDE either 1.8.9 OR 1.8.12 BUT the VS code extension is broken. So

- You have to downgrade to January release 1.42 **AND**
- Then turn off automatic updates for the moment.

How to get the release: [Click here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_42)

Before installing /downgrade
The excessive debug logging is caused by running Java with -DDEBUG=true. Adding -DDEBUG=false to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino_debug.l4j.ini fixes it for now.

Comment: Thank you corebreaker007. I was aware of the debug logging problem as that was the first issue I ran into and after some research, I was able to work it out. I'm using Arduino ide 1.8.12, Visual studio code 1.44 and Arduino extension 0.3.0. I will try to downgrade following your advice. After trying to find a replacement for Arduino IDE as the editor is far from being perfect, I thought that Visual Code could be a fit as it's simple but complete. It's a pity because it seems there are many minor mistakes that are time-consuming to have a platform you can rely on. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also check out the PlatformIO extension for VSCode!